# how to centering the content when shrink the window in css3

Tags: html, css, nav

Here is my code for navigation:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <nav class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">COMPANY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MARKETS/SOLUTIONS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS/SERVICES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">BUSINESSES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">INVESTORS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            </header>
            </div>
```

css3:

```
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:12px;
}
.wrapper{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
nav ul{
    background-color: red;

}
nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:15px;

}
nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
nav ul li:first-child:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color:none;
}
nav ul li:hover{
    background-color:#000;
}
```

JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ubz7Lcft/6/

I need like this when normal window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN0WV.jpg  , and i need like this when shrink the window https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qer1S.jpg

Plase help me to fix this, i already tried all possible ways..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, does adding:

```
text-align: center;
```

to .wrapper get what you want?

EDIT: To limit this to cases where the screen is 700px wide or wider, for example:

```
@media (min-width: 700px) {
    .wrapper {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: And i don't want text-align:center; because, in normal window the contents are  should show in left.

Comment: So what defines when you want to change from left-justified to centered?   Sounds like you might want to look as ***CSS Media Queries*** like `@media (max-width: 600px) { ... }`

Comment: .wrapper should be full width.. not use 960px

Comment: from your answer, in normal window showed center.. but i need left side..  when i shrink the window the contents are show in center.